# Retreive the current Kerberos KVNO from Active Directory

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos

I have a Kerberos problem with a Linux host connecting to a Windows KDC. I suspect that Kerberos key with the wrong version is to blame.

One way to be shure would be to delete the SPN and create it anew, but this is in a production environment and I must debug in "read-only", if you will.

How can I retreive the current Kerberos KVNO from a principal in Active Directory ?

Comment: The Windows implementation of Kerberos V5 ignores the `KVNO` value, and simply tries to use the 2 known secrets (current and previous) it has available to decrypt requests. It simply doesn't matter

Comment: I forgot to mention the client is Linux. Active Directory must be holding it, since it increments it each time ktpass is called.

Comment: All the same, if the KDC is Windows, it still doesn't matter

Comment: The kvno is crucial for sssd. If they do not match you'll see this in /var/log/sssd/krb5_child.log (on ubuntu 16.04) `Cannot find key for <principal> kvno <KVNO from AD> in keytab`. The KDC is Windows in this case.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, the question clearly states that the client is Linux, where kvno very much does matter.  What Windows systems do is interesting, but does not answer the question.

Comment: @Medievalist If you observe the timestamps you'll find that OP edited the question _after_ my initial comment :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>I'm incredulous as to whether KVNO has anything to do with your problem</strike>, OK maybe with Linux clients, but anyway, use Wireshark/Network Monitor:

[image: kvno]

Key Version Numbers are described in MS-KILE section 3.1.5.8.

By the way, Mathias R. Jessen is correct in that in that Windows typically ignores KVNOs. But they are still implemented in an RFC-complaint way.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/openspecification/to-kvno-or-not-to-kvno-what-is-the-version

> No, Windows does not pay attention to KVNO. It simply ignores it.

But the KVNO does have some significance in an RODC environment:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/openspecification/notes-on-kerberos-kvno-in-windows-rodc-environment

Some more info here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150204183217/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2716037

> In an environment with one or more RODCs authentication may fail when
> interacting with certain MIT based Kerberos devices in one of the
> following scenarios.
>
> ·          The client is an MIT device which received a TGT from
> Windows KDC on RODC
>
> ·          The client passes a TGT generated by Windows KDC on RODC to
> MIT Device which in turn uses the TGT to request a TGS on behalf of
> the calling user.
>
> In both scenarios the TGT will have been issued by an RODC where the
> **msDS-SecondaryKrbTgtNumber** associated with the krbtgt account for that
> RODC will have a value greater than 32767.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem turned out to be irrelevant with the key version. But your answer is "accept" worthy, by large !

Answer (score 10):

With PowerShell's AD Cmdlets it's possible to query for kvno:

```
PS> import-module ActiveDirectory
    ^^^ if this fails, find a Windows server where it is installed
PS> get-aduser <username> -property msDS-KeyVersionNumber
```

Comment: If it's a machine trust account you need "get-adcomputer" but otherwise it's the same syntax.
get-adcomputer <computername$> -property msDS-KeyVersionNumber

Answer (score 6):

```
dsquery * -filter sAMAccountName=Accountname -attr msDS-KeyVersionNumber
```

Comment: Please add some more details ...

Answer (score 4):

On linux you can use **kvno** command to retreive it from KDC

```
[root@XXXX XXX]# kvno host/XXXX

host/XXXX@TEST.COM: kvno = 13
```

Comment: This only queries the locally cached credentials. I have had plenty of cases where it returns an outdated kvno - and /var/log/sssd/krb5_child.log told me what the actual version number should be in error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Query from a AD joined linux server:

```
net ads search  -P  '(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=HOSTNAME))'  msDS-KeyVersionNumber
```

replace **HOSTNAME** with your hostname.

Answer (score 1):

my team has had to work through this before and we found the following works on some Linux systems to get the KVNO number:

```
adquery user $USER --dump | grep KeyVersionNumber
```

Of course, you can replace the `$USER` with an actual user needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your specific fix was for this problem, for me I found the another error mentioning pam couldn't work out the domain from the hostname. When I checked the /etc/hosts file wasn't consistent with the hostname set via hostnamectl.

```
# Broken
127.0.0.1 hostname hostname.example.com
# Fixed
127.0.0.1 hostname.example.com hostname
```

Would have thought this would have affected the problem, but it starting behaving after I set this.